# How to revert jenkins Safe restart?

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins was having issues and I safe rebooted it in order to solve the issue but the issue got solved the reboot. Some jobs have ours to run so is there way to cancel the reboot?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you talk about jenkins cli?

There is no command to abort the `safeRestart`.
Use `quiteDown`, `cancelQuietDown` instead and `safeRestart` only if needed.

> `safeRestart`: Puts Jenkins into the
> quiet mode, wait for existing builds to be completed, and then restart
> Jenkins
> `quietDown`: Put Jenkins in a Quiet mode, in preparation for a restart. In that mode Jenkins don’t start any build
> `cancelQuietDown`: Cancel the effect of the “quiet-down” command